# How do I return an int data from a static void method to main method?

Tags: java, methods, int, return-value

So everything is working but my only issue is that I'm not sure how to return a piece data from my `speakLine()` method. I'm trying to print the amount of right answers I got from a set of problems.

Something like this: you got "2" out of 3 correct.

```
Public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int cal;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        int num1 = randomA();

        int num2 = randomB();

        cal = num1 + num2;

        speakLines(num1, num2, cal);
    }
```

I need the "count" int from speakLine method():

```
    System.out.println("You got " + count + "of " + i + "right");
} // end main()
```

This is the method

```
public static void speakLines(int num1, int num2, int cal) {
    int count = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Voice voice;

    // set up a Voicemanager object and use it to link voice with a                     particular voice
    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    voice = voiceManager.getVoice("kevin16");

    // load the selected voice
    voice.allocate();

    // begin speaking the text
    System.out.println("what is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + ":");
    voice.speak("what is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + ":");

    //talk
    System.out.println("Please enter answer");
    int answer = scanner.nextInt();

    //talk
    if (answer == cal) {
        System.out.println("That's right");
        voice.speak("That's right");
        count += 1;
```

"Count +=1" above ^ -- I need to print this count int from the main() method. This is the data "count" that I'm trying to return to the main method. This tells me how many answers the user got right.

```
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is" + cal);
        voice.speak("Sorry, the answer is " + cal);
    }

} // end speakLines()

public static int randomA() {
    int A; 
    A = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    return A;

}

public static int randomB() {
    int B;
    B = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
    return B;
}
// end randomB()
} // end class
```

Now I know static void methods do not return data. But I know there should be a way to return a specific data.

Comment: From the looks of it, you may want to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Does `speakLines` have to be `static void`, or just `static`?

Comment: @frenchDolphin I think you are asking question, OP cannot answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class variable `public static int count;` to replace the local variable `count` in the `speakLines` method.

After doing so, you should be able to access and print `score` in the main method.

Comment: Yeah. This works but it's giving me the output for every single loop. I just want to print "System.out.println("You got " + count + " of " + index + "right.");" once after the program finishes. Any ideas?

Comment: I have another idea which is reflected in my edited answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: by "class variable" you mean outside the main method? If so, "non-static variable score cannot be referenced from a static context" I'm getting this error from "score = count;" hm?

Comment: Did you try making score static?

Answer (score 0):

The return code is probably not want you want here. You likely want to write the answer to Standard output. This way some other program could pick it up. There are various methods on `System.out` that will write to standard output.

If you want to use a java program to be a part of a chain of programs, you use standard input and standard output.

That `System.out.println` is causing the program to send output. This could be read by another program. For example you could run this and redirect it's output to a file: `java -jar yourjar > out.txt`

You can also use a pipe character to send this output to another program:

```
java -jar yourJar | grep of
```

I don't know what specifically you want to do with the output.

Comment: I just want to print "count" that is in the speakLine()method from the main method. That's all i need.

Comment: Why don't you just call System.out.println from speak line? You can print from anywhere in any program.

Comment: I just want to print "count" after the program finishes not for every loop. I feel you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a static filed on the containing class (the one that is above the main function) and reset it at the beginning of speakLines.

Usually you don't need static for that but since the main is a static method it cannot access non static fields of the containing class.

or

Use a class parameter that will hold the int value, and also reset the value at at the beginning of speakLines.

Comment: I assumed this is kind of test question or something , cause for sure the best way is to return a value and not use void.

Answer (score 0):

Taking help from the @DizzyCode, how about-
1. Declare <kbd>public static int count</kbd> in *line 2*
2. Initialize variable <kbd>count</kbd> in *line 9* 
3. Comment initialisation of your local variable 'count' in the method 'speakLines'

```
//******************************
public static int count;

Public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int cal;
    int i;
//set count to 0 before the loop starts
    count=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        int num1 = randomA();

        int num2 = randomB();

        cal = num1 + num2;

        speakLines(num1, num2, cal);
    }

        System.out.println("You got " + count + "of " + i + "right");
} // end main()


public static void speakLines(int num1, int num2, int cal) {
//**************************************
//make this count invalid and create a public static count variable before main method
//    int count = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Voice voice;

    // set up a Voicemanager object and use it to link voice with a                     particular voice
    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    voice = voiceManager.getVoice("kevin16");

    // load the selected voice
    voice.allocate();

    // begin speaking the text
    System.out.println("what is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + ":");
    voice.speak("what is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + ":");

    //talk
    System.out.println("Please enter answer");
    int answer = scanner.nextInt();

    //talk
    if (answer == cal) {
        System.out.println("That's right");
        voice.speak("That's right");
        count += 1;} 
        else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is" + cal);
        voice.speak("Sorry, the answer is " + cal);
    }

} // end speakLines()

public static int randomA() {
    int A; 
    A = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    return A;

}

public static int randomB() {
    int B;
    B = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
    return B;
}
// end randomB()
} // end class
```

Comment: Yessss!! I see it now. Thank you.